# Can Notepad++ insert a carriage return or new line with a User Defined Language?

Tags: notepad++

I have output from a system that is one long string.  A tilde (~) denotes an end of a sequence.  I would like to create a user-defined language in Notepad++'s Language menu so that when I select it, it will insert a carriage return after the ~.  Can't seem to figure out how to do this or if it is even possible.

I read through the documentation and cannot seem to find any reference to this.

Comment: This will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168991/user-defined-language-comment-style-needs-n-newline-in-notepad

Comment: @Rameshkumar Do you think that's in fact the same question?

Comment: I don't think this is the same question.  I read through that one already and tried a few things.  It seems like that is just trying to define where the comments begin and end and NOT add a carriage return at a specific point/character.